# Simplify a Logic Expression using NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have a doubt at using Natural Language ToolKit (NLTK). I'm trying to make an app in order to translate a Natural Language Question into it's logic representation, and query to a database.

The result I got after using the simplify() method under nltk.sem.logic package and got the following expression:

```
exists z2.(owner(fido, z2) & (z0 = z2))
```

But what I need is to simplify it as follow:

```
owner(fido, z0)
```

Is there another method that could reduce the sentence as I want?

Comment: Be warned that getting the representation of toy sentences is a very, **very** long way from doing the same with unrestricted natural language input. To have a realistic chance of success, switch to a shallow approach without real semantic analysis.

Comment: Is just a practice I'm doing. The input is restricted to a very limited subset of the English language. I build a small feature based grammar, and using lambda expressions to get a logic expression (the one I simplified), but need it to be even more simplified. There's a database with dog names and his owners, and I'm trying to connect the logical expression to the database and get the answer. 

I'm having some troubles right now, do you know if there  are some book or a link where I could achieve that? 

Thanks!

Comment: That makes more sense... "limited subset of English" (a.k.a. "fragment") is a very different matter from "natural language question"! Carry on, then. I can only advise you to study the Prover9 documentation, and maybe an introduction to formal semantics (if you're not already familiar with that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NLTK, `simplify()` performs beta reduction ([according to the book](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html)) which is not what you need. What you are asking is only doable with theorem provers when you apply certain tactics. Which in this case, you either need to know what you expect to get at the end or you know what kinds of axioms can be applied to get such result.

The theorem prover in NLTK is [Prover9](http://www.nltk.org/howto/inference.html) which provides tools to check entailment relations. Basically, you can only check if there is a proof with a limited number of steps from a list of expressions (premises) to a goal expression. In your case for example, this was the result:

```
============================== PROOF =================================

% -------- Comments from original proof --------
% Proof 1 at 0.00 (+ 0.00) seconds.
% Length of proof is 8.
% Level of proof is 4.
% Maximum clause weight is 4.
% Given clauses 0.

1 (exists x (owner(fido,x) & y = x)) # label(non_clause).  [assumption].
2 owner(fido,x) # label(non_clause) # label(goal).  [goal].
3 owner(fido,f1(x)).  [clausify(1)].
4 x = f1(x).  [clausify(1)].
5 f1(x) = x.  [copy(4),flip(a)].
6 -owner(fido,c1).  [deny(2)].
7 owner(fido,x).  [back_rewrite(3),rewrite([5(2)])].
8 $F.  [resolve(7,a,6,a)].

============================== end of proof ==========================
```

In NLTK python:

```
from nltk import Prover9
from nltk.sem import Expression
read_expr = Expression.fromstring
p1 = read_expr('exists z2.(owner(fido, z2) & (z0 = z2))')
c = read_expr('owner(fido, z0)')
result = Prover9().prove(c, [p1])
print(result)
# returns True
```

**UPDATE**

In case that you insist on using available tools in python and you want to manually check this certain pattern with regular expressions. You can probably do something like this with regular expression (I don't approve but let's try my nasty tactic):

```
def my_nasty_tactic(exp):
    parameter = re.findall(r'exists ([^.]*)\..*', exp)
    if len(parameter) == 1:
        parameter = parameter[0]
        substitution = re.findall(r'&[ ]*\([ ]*([^ ]+)[ ]*=[ ]*'+parameter+r'[ ]*\)', exp)
        if len(substitution) == 1:
             substitution = substitution[0]
             exp_abs = re.sub(r'exists(?= [^.]*\..*)', "\ ", exp)
             exp_abs = re.sub(r'&[ ]*\([ ]*' + substitution + '[ ]*=[ ]*'+parameter+r'[ ]*\)', '', exp_abs)
             return read_expr('(%s)(%s)' % (exp_abs, substitution)).simplify()
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
my_nasty_tactic('exists z2.(owner(fido, z2) & (z0 = z2))')
# <ApplicationExpression owner(fido,z0)>
```

Comment: Being true the prove, I could get the desired result with a regular expression, right? All the expressions that has "exists" are similar. Have the expression with a numbered variable, and in the end there's the equality with the z0 variable.

Comment: I cannot tell what exactly you mean by "get the desired result", but regular expressions and theorem proving do not go together. You're mixing apples and skyscrapers!

Comment: What I'm telling is that, in order to get the desired expression, I could get the "owner(fido, z2)" part out of the whole expression, using a RegEx, replace z2 with z0, and get the expression I wanted.

Comment: I need the expression without quantifiers.

Comment: Well, to be able to use regular expressions, coupled with beta-reduction, first you need to make certain assumptions about the expression that you are processing. I can give you a possible why to do it (my solution), but I don't know if you can scale it up for all sorts of expressions.

Comment: I will put an update to my answer based on regular expression. Basically, what I have in mind is to replace the existential quantifier with lambda, then remove the equality relation for the abstracted variable, and put it as an argument of the lambda function. Then you can use simplify. But, can you scale this solution for your problems? I don't know :)

Comment: Wow, that's just what I was looking for.